# Displaying "NaN" in a cell depending on the datasource value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a Style on my data grid cell defined as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Editors:XamNumericEditor}" x:Key="MyVisibleStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource InPointStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="-nnnnnnnnnnn.nnnn"/>
    <Setter Property="Format" Value="#,##0.000;-#,##0.000" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataItem.IsPermissioned}" Value="False" >
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

So depending on the value of `DataItem.IsPermissioned` I set the Visibility of the cell.

How can I change this so that if `IsPermissioned=false` then I display "NaN" in the cell?

Answer (score 1):

You need to alternate the content property instead. So use the part below or add your own content depending on the cell pattern.

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="NaN" />
```

Comment: Hi Herdo. It's an Infragistics grid and when I do that I get an error "Connot find the stlye property 'Content'" ... Do you know what I can do here?

Comment: Sorry @Bob, I'm not familiar with Infragistics. Did you visit the [Community](http://www.infragistics.com/community/)/[Help](http://www.infragistics.com/help/) sites of Infragistics?

Due to the example code of Infragistics I have 2 ideas right now:
1.: Tried `<Setter Property="Content" Value="NaN" />`
I'm not sure if this will work with a bound property.
2.: I guess you have a bound property. You may edit this property instead?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a converter, which implements IValueConverter?

In the binding you would use it like

`Binding="{Binding Path=Something, Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}}"`

and your converter would be something like

`public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (validation on the value)
        { return "NaN" } }`